# how to export json data to pdf file with specify format with Nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, pdf

I am a beginner with nodejs. And I am writing a program, which convert text data from json file to pdf file: 
This is my input file (input.json)

```
{

"Info":

    {
    "Company": "ABC",
    "Team": "JsonNode"
    },
    "Number of members": 4,
    "Time to finish": "1 day"
}
```

And I want to convert it to a .pdf (report.pdf) file with following style.

1. Info

   1.1 Company

   ABC

   1.2 Team

   JsonNode
2. Number of members
       4
3. Time to finish
       1 day

My problems are:

1: How to change style from input.json file to style of report.pdf.

2: How to convert from .json format to .pdf format.

Could anyone help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of html to pdf services. I suggest you use one of those and convert your json to formatted html. Then you can send your html/json output to their service and it will return a pdf file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to make html template and then render your json into html template.

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table> 
<tr>Company</tr>
{{info.Company}}
<tr>Team</tr>
{{info.Team}}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now On your js file you have to give path of your  template and also      create a folder in order to store your pdf file.

```
     var pdf = require('html-pdf');
 var options = {format: 'Letter'};
exports.Topdf = function (req, res) {
 var info = {

 "Company": "ABC",
 "Team": "JsonNode",
 "Number of members": 4,
"Time to finish": "1 day"
}
res.render('path to your tempalate', {
    info: info,
}, function (err, HTML) {
    pdf.create(HTML, options).toFile('./downloads/employee.pdf', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
    })
  })
 }
```

Try with this hope it works.

Comment: @Vishnu: Yes, I already corrected it , but it still didn't work

Comment: I meet this issue: res.render('./template.html', {
   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Comment: Hi @MariyaJames . I did as your guide, but maybe having something abnormal with my method: I use your .js code and save it as (test.js) then I make another .js file (test1.js) with content as follow: 
var test = require("./test.js");
test.topdf();
After that I run test1.js file. "node test1.js". the issue above still happens, Could you please give me a suggestion in more detail. and how did you run the .js code?

Comment: app.get('/', test.topdf()); As i told you if you are using express you have to call function using routes. as i shown here. Then only you will have req,res object. Try to http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I did same way as ur guide I code work well !

Comment: Hi, How to pass the api url to get the report instead of hard code

Comment: hi @MariyaJames I tried your answer but info not populating in html 
the output :
Company {{info.Company}} Team {{info.Team}}

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the layout using html as,

```
<ul>
 <li>Info: </li>
 <ul>
  <li>Company: {{info.Company}}</li>
  <li>Team: {{info.Team}}</li>
 </ul>
 <li>Number of members: {{info.numberofmembers}}</li>
 <li>Time to finish: {{info.timetofinish}}</li>
<ul>
```

Now you have to store this html in a variable say "layout".
Then create the pdf as,

```
function generatePdf(layout, file) {
console.log('generating pdf');

var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

wkhtmltopdf(html, {
    output: file,
    "viewport-size": "1280x1024",
    "page-width": "400",
    "page-height": "600"
});
}
```

Where file is the path where you want to save your file.

Comment: Thank you very much @Akshay Kumar. But I have some more questions:
1: How to declare variable "layout" and use it in .js file?
2: How to html layout use data from .json file ( when I change the content of json file, content of html also auto change follow it)?
3: How to creat a stype exactly same as style in my report.pdf file ( which was post in question above)?
I only work with C/C++ before, I have just used nodejs,html two days ago so could you please answer more detail and complete your code will more useful to me.

Comment: In .js just declare the variable as

Comment: In .js just declare the variable as var = "<ul><li>Info: </li<ul><li>Company: {{info.Company}}</li><li>Team: {{info.Team}}</li></ul>
 <li>Number of members: {{info.numberofmembers}}</li>
 <li>Time to finish: {{info.timetofinish}}</li><ul>". Read about parsing json data and construct the html as a string. For the numbering on points you can use "<ol>" tags in place of "<ul>" tags.

Comment: When I run .js file. I didn't see log "generating pdf"(no error log also). It mean it doesn't go into function generatePdf. Do you know what is problem here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91378/discussion-between-akshay-kumar-and-toandd).

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions saying first convert into html and then to pdf but instead one can directly generate pdf using "pdfmake" or "pdfkit" library. I've used it and its very good library. pdfkit is the parent library over which pdfmake has been made.
pdfmake is very simple library compared to pdfkit (this is what I feel).
pdfmake *lacks some features* like bookmarks and toc(table of content header) linkage to respective page.

**pdfmake**: https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/

**pdfkit**: http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this question by converting **JSON to PDF directly** without converting to HTML first by using `jsPDF`.

Code:

```
jsonData = {
    "Info":{
       "Company":"ABC",
       "Team":"JsonNode"
    },
    "Number of members":4,
    "Time to finish":"1 day"
 }

var pdf2 = new jsPDF();
var i = 1;
var row = 1;
for(data in jsonData){
    var j = 1;
    if(typeof(jsonData[data]) === 'object' && jsonData[data] !== null){
        for(innerData in jsonData[data])
        {
            pdf2.text(i + ". " + data, 10, 20 + (row*10));
            if(jsonData[data][innerData] !== undefined){
                row = row+1;
                pdf2.text(i + "." + j+ innerData, 10, 20 + (row*10));
                row = row+1;
                pdf2.text(jsonData[data][innerData], 10, 20 + (row*10));
                j=j+1;
            }
            row = row+1;
        }
    }
    else {
        pdf2.text(i + ". " + data + " " + jsonData[data].toString(), 10, 20 + (row*10));
    }
    row=row+1;
    i = i+1;
}
pdf2.save('Stackoverflow.pdf');
```

To install jsPDF: `npm install jspdf --save`.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Hope this helps someone! :)

Snapshot of generated PDF:
[image]